# "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed error in Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a `REST`service and i tested it on `Chrome REST Console` . There its working fine and i am getting the response but while consuming the same by jquery Ajax i am getting `"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed error in Ajax Call` and `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:64132/Auth. (Reason: CORS request failed).` error.Here is my Ajax code..

```
var UserDetails = { "UserName": "Bond", "Password": "password" };

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:64132/Auth',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: UserDetails,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {

        alert(data.UserName);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("some error");
    }
});
```

Please help me to correct this and successfully call the Service.Thanks..

Update

when i am trying to call the Service from Chrome i am getting following error in console..

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Test.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:64132/Auth. No  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: what you are using at server side

Comment: `type: 'POST',` try with `type: 'GET',`

Comment: @cxminer I am getting error in chrome also ..Please see my updated post for exact error..

Comment: This is a CORS issue, you need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:64132/` in your Rest service.

Comment: What url are you using to access this webpage ?

Comment: @ShailendraSharma I am using ServiceStack Authentication Service

Comment: @Lara check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991417/accessing-servicestack-authenticated-service-using-ajax

Comment: @Hacketo I am accessing this webpage directly from my HTML ..I am not using any Server for this

Comment: @Lara if you were serving this HTML on localhost I guess there would be no CORS problem

Comment: @Hacketo Its in localHost only and i am getting this problem..

Comment: @Lara what does "directly from my HTML" mean? Clicking on a .html file and opening it in the browser from your file system? Or accessing it through the server you have running on localhost:64132?

Comment: @dman2306 It means ` Clicking on a .html file and opening it in the browser `.

Comment: @Lara then you're not running from localhost, you're running on file:// and accessing localhost, hence CORS. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers have very strict rules about retrieving content from different "domains". Retrieving content from your local file system (your HTML/script) is not the same as making a network request to `localhost` (your ajax call), so Chrome treats it as a cross-domain request.

In order for the cross-domain request to succeed, you either need to serve the HTML content/script from a `http://localhost:64132/` URL as well (so they're in the same domain), or you need to set up your REST service to implement the CORS dance to allow your `file:` URL to access it.

Without knowing the details of how your REST service is implemented, it's impossible to give specific instructions for either option. Which you choose will will depend on how you intend to deploy the page and service in real life (same domain or not) and ease of implementation. If your REST service is deployed in some sort of container it may provide options for implementing CORS, and/or for serving the initial page.

Random example of the same issue (although the exact solution here is unlikely to work for your specific case): [Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when Origin 'null' when trying to post data to a LOCAL application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770192/access-control-allow-origin-header-when-origin-null-when-trying-to-post-data-t)